# Is it correct use of Android MediaStore.Images by content resolver?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I develop simple Jetpack Compose app that can take photo or pick it from gallery and send it to server. I'm confused if I do it right.

Target: Android 8+ and required permissions granted (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)

TL;DR

> I receive 2 different kind of URIs, so I need to create 2 different methods to get file path both use contentResolver.query on MediaStore.Images. I'm not sure if both two methods are required.
>
> AsyncImage(model = uri, contentDescription = "image") - works well on any of that URIs.
>
> Maybe I can use URI to send file via Retrofit instead of File?

Thanks for any hints.

My code:

```kotlin
val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        onResult = { success ->
            viewModel.handlePictureTake(success)
        }
    )
val imagePicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        onResult = { uri ->
            if (uri != null) {
                viewModel.onAttachmentEvent(AttachmentEvent.AddAttachment(uri.toString()))
            }
        }
    )
```

For taking photo I use

```kotlin
fun getImageUri(context: Context): Uri? {
            val timestamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

            val resolver = context.contentResolver
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "image_$timestamp")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            }

            return resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
        }
val uri = getImageUri(context)
if (uri != null) {
   cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
}
```

getImageUri create URI like: **content://media/external/images/media/....**

On the other hand, when I pick image like this:

```kotlin
imagePicker.launch("image/*")
```

I received URI in this scheme: **content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/....**

When I try to send file using Retrofit I need to get **File** for multipart upload.
I created 2 methods for each URI type to get file path:

```kotlin
// Get file path for In-App created files by URI: (content://media/external/images/media/....)
fun getFilePathFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    var filePath: String? = null
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return filePath ?: getDocumentPath(context, uri)
}

// Get file path for other App created files by URI: (content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/....)
private fun getDocumentPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    return try {
        var filePath = ""
        val fileId: String = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
        val id = fileId.split(":".toRegex())[1]
        val column = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val selector = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?"
        val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, selector, arrayOf(id), null
        )
        cursor?.use {
            val columnIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0])
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            }
        }
        return filePath
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: `Maybe I can use URI to send file via Retrofit instead of File?` Yes you can. Open an inputstream for the uri and then use -google- inputstreamrequestbody.

Comment: Main problem with InputStream is that, using context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) on uri like (content://media/external/images/media/....) throws exception: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). My method return valid readable path for this URI

Comment: If you had a valid readable path then you would not have a problem. Just use the uri at the moment you got it in the same activity.

Comment: @blackapps my confusion is about using 2 different method to grab valid file path or how to use URI as universal file source. I'm not sure is it OK when using the same content resolver and MediaStore.Images query by two different methods. Maybe it is totally fine? :)

Comment: You should not try to get a file path for an uri. Completely wrong. Throw all that code away. Just use the uri as you were told. Just open that stream at the moment you get that uri (in onActivityResult() probably) and you will see that you can open a stream.

Comment: `Maybe I can use URI to send file via Retrofit instead of File?` Yes you can. Do it!

Comment: I use Jetpack Compose now. In old way I do it a lot of times and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @blackapps. As you suggested I use InputStreamRequestBody and it works.

Following the GitHub issue:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196

Android documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#open-file-stream

```kotlin
class InputStreamRequestBody(private val contentType: MediaType?, private val contentResolver: ContentResolver, private val uri: Uri?) : RequestBody() {

    init {
        if (uri == null) throw NullPointerException("uri == null")
    }

    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        return contentType
    }

    override fun contentLength(): Long {
        return -1
    }

    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
        contentResolver.openInputStream(uri!!)?.use {
            sink.writeAll(it.source())
        }
    }
}
```